# WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing: action

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

We're trying to access a webservice (which I believe is also coded using WCF, but I have no control over it whatsoever) and I get an exception:

> [System.ServiceModel.FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception(v=vs.100).aspx): WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing: action.
>   Server stack trace:

```cs
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(
   ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs,
   TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(
   IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

> Exception rethrown at [0]:

```cs
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(
   IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(
   MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at ClientName.ProjectName.Services.ServiceName.ServiceNameSoap.CallServiceName(
   Request request)
at ClientName.ProjectName.Scheduler.ThirdPartyName.ProcessServiceName.Execute(
   Object state) in ...\ProcessServiceName.cs:line 65
```

The calling code in `ProcessServiceName.Execute` reads:

```cs
Request serviceRequest = request.BuildServiceRequest();
Result result = client.CallServiceName(serviceRequest);
LogServiceErrors(db, request.ServiceNameRequestId, result.errors);
```

and the exception is coming from the second of those lines, which calls directly into the WCF code autogenerated by the Service Reference, calling [`System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>. Channel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344730(v=vs.100).aspx)`.CallServiceName(request)`; the method `BuildServiceRequest` just takes the database object and converts it to the object required by the webservice.

The relevant part of the `App.config` (this is called within a Windows Service) reads:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
         <binding name="webBinding">
         </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="ThirdPartySoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
             maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
             maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
            <security mode="Transport">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="www.serviceprovider.com"/>
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="ServiceNameSoap"
       address="https://www.serviceprovider.com/ServiceName.asmx"
       binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ThirdPartySoap"
       contract="ServiceName.ServiceNameSoap"/>
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Given that all the code that does the actual webservice work is from within WCF, I don't quite understand what the problem is but, presumably, I need something slightly different in my `App.config` to prevent it.

Having [looked on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=FaultException%3A+WSE012%3A+"not+a+valid+SOAP+message"+"information+is+missing%3A+action"), I'm finding nothing of any help. On StackOverflow, [this unanswered WCF question from September 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7570610/205245) is of no help; custom bindings ([answer from November 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676838/205245) and [link about WSE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/256455d7-079c-4f09-84eb-202c121a2664)) don't help (and I barely understand them), and both [a forum answer from November 2009](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2672) and [a ColdFusion thing from October 2009](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2326727) are unrelated. All the other Google hits I'm seeing are duplicates of these links.

*Any* assistance would be greatly appreciated!

---

### Edit to add more detail

[Wiktor Zychla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941240/wiktor-zychla) has rightly pointed out that the problem could (theoretically) be in the proxy classes. However, these classes are wholly unedited from the classes generated automatically; for example:

```cs
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ClientName.ProjectName.Services.ServiceName
{
   [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
   public interface ServiceNameSoapChannel : ServiceNameSoap, IClientChannel {}

   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
   public partial class ServiceNameSoapClient : ClientBase<ServiceNameSoap>,
     ServiceNameSoap
   {
     public ServiceNameSoapClient() { }

     public ServiceNameSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
       base(endpointConfigurationName) { }

     public ServiceNameSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName,
       string remoteAddress) :
       base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) { }

     public ServiceNameSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName,
       EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
       base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) { }

     public ServiceNameSoapClient(Binding binding,
       EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : base(binding, remoteAddress) { }

     public Result CallServiceName(Request request)
     { return base.Channel.CallServiceName(request); }
   }
}
```

All the other proxy classes are similarly unedited from the autogenerated code (which I've edited here for whitespace and namespace optimisation, so that it fits better on screen within StackOverflow; the three namespaces I've added `using` statements for were fully-qualified on all class references, as was the namespace I've redacted to `ClientName.ProjectName.Services.ServiceName` in these samples.

Having added [WCF Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.100).aspx), I get the following in my message log. (This is from a different service call than the code above, but throwing the same exception, partly because this service call is simpler, partly because not all service calls are being logged, for some reason. The only edit I have made is to make the error message legible without horizontal scrolling.)

```xml
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-18T12:00:04.7166250Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="ClientName.ProjectName.Scheduler" ProcessID="8600" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>MachineNameRedacted</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2013-01-18T12:00:04.7166250+00:00" Source="TransportSend" Type="System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter+OperationFormatterMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
          <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <s:Header>
              <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.serviceprovider.com/RedactedActionName</a:Action>
              <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:395d6394-5f4b-4954-8df0-8fb82d17072a</a:MessageID>
              <a:ReplyTo>
                <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
              </a:ReplyTo>
              <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://www.serviceprovider.com/ServiceName.asmx</a:To>
            </s:Header>
            <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <RedactedActionName xmlns="http://www.serviceprovider.com">
                <brandId>2</brandId>
              </RedactedActionName>
            </s:Body>
          </s:Envelope>
        </MessageLogTraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-18T12:00:04.7635000Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="ClientName.ProjectName.Scheduler" ProcessID="8600" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>MachineNameRedacted</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2013-01-18T12:00:04.7635000+00:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
          <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
            <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
              <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
              <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b72c6f30-8409-4b55-8c79-056d82f990a5</wsa:MessageID>
              <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
            </env:Header>
            <soap:Body>
              <soap:Fault>
                <soap:Code>
                  <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
                </soap:Code>
                <soap:Reason>
                  <soap:Text xml:lang="en">
                    WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because
                    the following information is missing: action.
                  </soap:Text>
                </soap:Reason>
              </soap:Fault>
            </soap:Body>
          </soap:Envelope>
        </MessageLogTraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
```

### Even more detail: ServiceNameSoap interface

As [Wiktor Zychla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941240/wiktor-zychla) has requested, here is the `ServiceNameSoap` interface declaration, from the autogenerated code, again edited only to fit better on screen (hence the `using`) and to redact the the client-confidential names:

```cs
using System.ServiceModel;

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel","4.0.0.0")]
[ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="https://www.serviceprovider.com/",
    ConfigurationName="ServiceName.ServiceNameSoap")]
public interface ServiceNameSoap
{
    [OperationContractAttribute(
        Action="https://www.serviceprovider.com/ServiceName",
        ReplyAction="*")]
    [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ClientRequest))]
    [return: MessageParameterAttribute(Name="result")]
    ClientName.ProjectName.Services.ServiceName.Result CallServiceName(
        ClientName.ProjectName.Services.ServiceName.Request request);
}
```

Comment: Owen, the issue could be related to your proxy class. Perhaps for some reason your proxied methods miss the required attributes. You could try to edit your question to post a sample of your proxy class plus fiddled actual soap request.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I've updated the question as requested; there's not much there that provides any further useful information, but I can see that it's useful to show that that is the case :)

Comment: One thing that has come up is that the service we're connecting to is definitely a WSE service, not a WCF service itself.

Comment: Owen, the key missing piece of the puzzle is your custom `ServiceNameSoap` interface which your service interface seem to inherit from. Most probably it contains (or: it SHOULD contain) the contract between your client and the server. The contract is expressed as a list of methods, each of them will (or: it SHOULD) have the `OperationContract` attribute with the `Action` set to a value. Note that under normal circumstances, the service proxy base interface is also generated automatically, from the wsdl contract available at the server.

Comment: @WiktorZychla More details, as requested. The interface is decorated with `OperationContractAttribute(Action="https://www.serviceprovider.com/ServiceName", ReplyAction="*")`, amongst others, as you can see.

Comment: I've just saw that your service is exposed on an .asmx endpoint which suggests that this is not a wcf service but rather an old asp.net service. Asp.net web services in contrary to wcf have very limited configuration options, they do not support ws/web binding (only basic http). My advice then is to switch to an old type proxy, generate it with wsdl.exe tool. You don't need any configuration and you can't use the wsHttpBinding but at least you should be able to call the service.

Comment: Worse, this is an old WSE service. Look at the exception message.

Comment: Aaaah, I didn't realise that old WSE services didn't support `wsHttpBinding`. Looks like I'm gonna have to do some recoding. Thanks, guys. @WiktorZychla If you can post that as an answer, I'll mark it with the fabled big green tick :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### We have a winner…

[Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941240/wiktor-zychla)'s comments led me to look at [Interop between WCF and WSE3.0](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2007/07/18/interoperability-between-wcf-and-wse-3-0.aspx), and try using [`MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageversion.soap12wsaddressingaugust2004(v=vs.100).aspx) in a [`CustomBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.custombinding(v=vs.100).aspx) by overriding [`Binding.CreateBindingElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.createbindingelements(v=vs.100).aspx) so that the method `ClientName.ProjectName.Services. ServiceName.ServiceNameSoapClient.CallServiceName` changed from:

```cs
public Result CallServiceName(Request request)
{
    return base.Channel.CallServiceName(request);
}
```

(as in the original question) to:

```cs
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

public Result CallTestDrive(Request request)
{
    BindingElementCollection elements
        = base.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
    elements.Find<MessageEncodingBindingElement>().MessageVersion
        = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004;
    base.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);

    return base.Channel.CallTestDrive(request);
}
```

(code adapted from [Modifying the Binding of a Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/11/16/modifying-the-binding-of-a-service.aspx) on [Nicholas Allen's WCF blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/)).

This would *seem* to have solved my problem. At last.

Thank you very much Wiktor and [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders); I wouldn't have got to this without your assistance.

---

### Edit: Another failed attempt below

Again for completeness's sake, I shall include another avenue I tried that did not work for  me. I also tried following the instructions from [this answer to the question WCF CustomBinding Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/830705/205245), creating a Custom Binding class in my namespace `ClientName.ProjectName.ServiceName`:

```cs
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

public class CustomWsHttpBinding : WSHttpBinding
{
    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        BindingElementCollection elements = base.CreateBindingElements();

        MessageEncodingBindingElement encodingElement
          = elements.Find<MessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        encodingElement.MessageVersion
          = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004;

        return elements;
    }
}
```

and adding it to the config with:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <bindingExtensions>
            <add name="CustomWsHttpBinding"
             type="ClientName.ProjectName.ServiceName.CustomWsHttpBinding, ClientName.ProjectName.ServiceName" />
        </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
        <CustomWsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServiceNameSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                 maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"
                     proxyCredentialType="None" realm="www.serviceprovider.com"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                     algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </CustomWsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!-- ... -->
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

*(joint effort with the OP)*

I've just saw that your service is exposed on an .asmx endpoint which suggests that this is not a wcf service but rather an old asp.net service. Asp.net web services in contrary to wcf have very limited configuration options, they do not support ws/web binding (only basic http). My advice then is to switch to an old type proxy, generate it with wsdl.exe tool. You don't need any configuration and you can't use the wsHttpBinding but at least you should be able to call the service.

Comment: Sorry not to be able to award you the fabled green tick, but I found a solution that involved substantially less recoding. I wouldn't have got there without all your help, though. Thank you _so_ much!

Comment: No problem. Good to see a correct answer so that others can quickly follow it in case of similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 2 years old but i figured i'd give the simplest solution. I may be rehashing the above answer. The trick is to realize that old school asmx services we pre ws-* acceptance. There are 2 versions(maybe more) of the WS-Addressing feature - August 2005 and the problematic August 2004. You can see these in SOAPUI where you have to manually change the WS-A version to "200408" when testing .asmx services. All that does is essentially change the ws-addressing header from:

> `<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">`

to

> `<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/addressing">`

so the question is, how would you do this in WCF? Simply, as the above stated is to NOT use wsHttpBinding but to use custom binding and setting the message version. Without further Adieu, the relevent WebConfig:

> `<system.serviceModel>
>       <client>
>         <endpoint address="http://localhost/some_old_school_garbage_service/adapterws.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AdapterWSSoap" contract="AdapterWS.AdapterWSSoap" name="LodestarASMX" />
>       </client>
>       <bindings>
>         <customBinding>
>           <binding name="AdapterWSSoap" >
>             <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="True"></security>
>             <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004"></textMessageEncoding>
>             <httpTransport/>
>           </binding>
>         </customBinding>`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: to mimic in .NET the WS-A version of 200408 I have in SoapUI, where I have the WSE requests working. Thanks! Works flawlessly.